# 15556 - 29.09.2023, 20:19:14 ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN"?

Tags: node.js, backend, nest

I've decorator:

```java
export const UserId = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user?.id ? Number(request.user.id) : null;
    },
);
```

My code:
If I try to get info without  @ApiBearerAuth(), I see all information about only first user. But with  @ApiBearerAuth() I have the Error.
We need method Get('/profile')

```java
@Controller('users')
@ApiTags('users')
@ApiBearerAuth()
export class UsersController {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
    
    @Get('/profile')
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    getProfile(@UserId() id: number) {
      console.log(id)
      return this.usersService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Function:

```java
async findById(id: number) {
    return this.repository.findOneBy({
     id,
    });
}
```

Why I see NaN? I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that when I get token I tried to take id from user.id, but I should take it from user._id.